# Query reg .ucf file in BASYS 2

Tags: verilog

I want to scroll hello world on seven segment display of BASYS2 board. I have created this .ucf file and I want to know whether I have to include clock and reset pins in .ucf. My .ucf file and verilog code is as follows:

```
module ssevenseg (
input clock, 
input reset, 
output a,
output b,
output c,
output d,
output e,
output f,
output g,
output [3:0] en
); 
reg [3:0] in0, in1, in2, in3;  // 
reg [28:0] tick_tock;  // to count for every 1s i.e holds count of 50 M
wire click; 


always @(posedge clock or posedge reset)
begin
if(reset)
tick_tock <= 0;
else if ( tick_tock==50000000)
tick_tock <= 0;
else
tick_tock <= tick_tock+1;
end

assign click = (( tick_tock==50000000)?1’b1:1’b0);  // click every second
reg [3:0] count1;  
always @(posedge click or posedge reset)
begin 
if (reset)
count1 <= 0;
else
count1 <= count1 + 1;
end



always @ (*)
begin
case (count1)
8’b00000000 :
begin
in0 = 4’b0001;  // H
in1 = 4’b0010;  // E
in2 = 4’b0011;  // L
in3 = 4’b0011;  // L
end
8’b00000001 :
begin
in0 = 4’b0010;  // E
in1 = 4’b0011;  // L
in2 = 4’b0011;  // L
in3 = 4’b0100;  // O
end
8’b00000010 :
begin
in0 = 4’b0011;  // L
in1 = 4’b0011;  // L
in2 = 4’b0100;  // O
in3 = 4’b0101;  // E
end
8’b00000011 :
begin
in0 = 4’b0011; // L
in1 = 4’b0100;  // O
in2 = 4’b0101;  // E
in3 = 4’b0100;  // O
end
8’b00000100 :
begin
in0 = 4’b0100;  // O
in1 = 4’b0101;  // E
in2 = 4’b0100;  // O
in3 = 4’b0110;  // r
end
8’b00000101 :
begin
in0 = 4’b0101;  // E
in1 = 4’b0100;  // O
in2 = 4’b0110;   // r
in3 = 4’b0011;  // L
end
8’b00000110 :
begin
in0 = 4’b0100;
in1 = 4’b0110;
in2 = 4’b0011;
in3 = 4’b0111;
end
endcase
end


localparam N = 18;

reg [N-1:0]count;  // the 18 bit counter that allows us to multiplex at 1000Hz

count <= 0;
always @ (posedge clock or posedge reset )
begin
if (reset)
count <= 0;
else
count <= count +1;
end

reg [3:0] display;
reg [3:0] temp_en;

always @ (*)
begin
case(count[N-1:N-2])    

2'b00 : 
    begin
    display = in0;
    temp_en = 4'b0111;  
    end

2'b01: 
     begin 
     display = in1;
     temp_en = 4'b1011;
     end

   2'b10: 
    begin
    display = in2;
    temp_en = 4'b1101;
    end

   2'b11:  
    begin
    display = in3;
    temp_en = 4'b1110;
    end
  endcase
 end   // end of begin

assign en = temp_en;


reg [6:0] temp_display;



always @(*)
begin

case (display)

4’b0000 : temp_display = 7’b1111110;  // if we give input ‘0’ nothing except ‘-‘ will be displayed
4’b0001 : temp_display = 7’b1001000;  // This will display ‘H’
4’b0010 : temp_display = 7’b0110000;  // to display ‘E’
4’b0011 : temp_display = 7’b1110001; // to display ‘L’
4’b0100 : temp_display = 7’b0000001; // to display ‘O’
4’b0101 : temp_display = 7’b1111010; // to display ‘r’
4’b0110 : temp_display = 7’b1000010; // to display ‘d’

default : temp_display = 7’b1111111; // blank

endcase
end
 assign {a,b,c,d,e,f,g} = temp_display ; 
endmodule




.UCF FILE :

NET a LOC = "L14";
NET b LOC = "H12";
NET c LOC = "N14";
NET d LOC = "N11";
NET e LOC = "P12";
NET f LOC = "L13";
NET g LOC = "M12";
NET en[3] LOC = "F12";
NET en[2] LOC = "J12";
NET en[1] LOC = "M13";
NET en[0] LOC = "K14";
```

Comment: FYI, you need to add a default case to your first `always @(*)`, the one with `case (count1)`. Currently the case is not complete so you are inferring complex latching logic that will take up huge area and have horrible timing. `in0` through `in3` need be assigned a determinate value in every possible branch withing the always block.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to add them to the ucf file, else the place and route will not know on which pin these signals must be linked.

you could also define the clock period constraint in the ucf like this (for a 1MHz clock):

```
NET "clock" TNM_NET = TNM_clock;
TIMESPEC "TS_clock" = PERIOD "TNM_clock" 1 us;
```